# Passing Javascript Array to Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I have a function in flask called array that takes in a list and prints out the items in the list:

```
def array(list):
    string = ""
    for x in list:
        string+= x
    return string
```

On the client side, I want to pass in a javascript array named str into this array. How would I do that? Here's what I have right now, but Flask isn't reading the added variable. Any ideas?

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);

            // str = str + "<br/><b>Pic</b> : <img src='"+ response.data[i].picture +"'/>";

            str[i] = response.data[i].picture;
        }
        window.location = "{{ url_for('array', str=list ) }}";
```

Comment: I'm kind of clueless in this area but this might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537254/passing-data-from-javascript-into-flask

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778167/return-data-from-html-js-to-python/14778465#14778465

Comment: you'd like for list to be transformed into a query string and appended to the URL there in the last line?

Comment: @JAL that's correct, none of the links Shashank posted seemed to show how to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: okay, so it needs to be in the name=val& sort of format. I've done this in django and PHP but not flask... but anyway, it's called query string encoding.

Comment: Oh yeah, you can do this in urllib of Python. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/python-urlencode-string

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Flask has a built in object called request. In request there is a multidict called args.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774265/flask-how-do-you-get-a-query-string-from-flask)

You can use `request.args.get('key')` to retrieve the value of a query string.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/example')
def example():
    # here we want to get the value of the key (i.e. ?key=value)
    value = request.args.get('key')
```

Of course this requires a get request (if you [use a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889107/sending-array-data-with-jquery-and-flask/40951200#40951200) then use `request.form`). [On the javascript side you can make a get request using pure javascript or jquery.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)
I'm going to use jquery in my example.

```
$.get(
    url="example",
    data={key:value}, 
    success=function(data) {
       alert('page content: ' + data);
    }
);
```

This is how you pass data from the client into flask. The function portion of the jquery code is how you pass data from flask to jquery. Let's say for example you have a view called /example and from the jquery side you pass in a key value pair of "list_name":"example_name"

```
from flask import jsonify
def array(list):
    string = ""
    for x in list:
        string+= x
    return string

@app.route("/example")
def example():
    list_name = request.args.get("list_name")
    list = get_list(list_name) #I don't know where you're getting your data from, humor me.
    array(list)
    return jsonify("list"=list)
```

and in the success function in jquery you'd say

```
  success=function(data) {
       parsed_data = JSON.parse(data)
       alert('page content: ' + parsed_data);
    }
```

[Note that flask does not allow for top level lists in json response for security reasons.](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security)

Comment: In case of POST, the data on the flask side may be in `request.json` when sent as json.