# Sending array data with jquery and flask

Tags: jquery, flask

I need to send data from a html page back into my Python application:

```
$.post("/test", {x: [1.0,2.0,3.0], y: [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]}, function(dat) {console.log(dat);});
```

on the server:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    print request.form.keys()
    print dir(request.form)
    print request.form["x[]"]
    return jsonify({"Mean": 10.0})
```

Much to my surprise the keys are

```
['y[]', 'x[]']
```

and

```
print request.form["x[]"]
```

results in 1.

What's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When sending POST data containing values that are arrays or objects, jQuery follows a [PHP convention of adding brackets to the field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543500/form-input-field-names-containing-square-brackets-like-fieldindex). It's not a web standard, but because PHP supports it out of the box it is popular.

As a result, the correct way of handling POST data with lists on the Flask side is indeed to append square brackets to the field names, as you discovered. You can retrieve *all* values of the list using [`MultiDict.getlist()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist):

```
request.form.getlist("x[]")
```

(`request.form` is a `MultiDict` object). This returns *strings*, not numbers. If you know the values to be numbers, you can tell the `getlist()` method to convert them for you:

```
request.form.getlist("x[]", type=float)
```

If you don't want the additional brackets to be applied, don't use arrays as values, or encode your data to JSON instead. You'll have to use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead though:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({x: [1.0,2.0,3.0], y: [2.0, 3.0, 1.0]}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(dat) { console.log(dat); }
});
```

and on the server side, use [`request.get_json()`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/#flask.Request.get_json) to parse the posted data:

```
data = request.get_json()
x = data['x']
```

This also takes care of handling the datatype conversions; you posted floating point numbers as JSON, and Flask will decode those back to float values again on the Python side.

Comment: You can also set the "traditional" parameter to true on the $.ajax to have jquery use the old style serialisation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the flask function `request.args.getlist('apps[]')` 
 to get the list from the js object you are passing to the server

```
var filter={}
 filter.startDate=$('#quant1').val(); 
 filter.endDate=$('#quant2').val(); 
 var checkedItems = [], counter = 0;
    $("#appNamesSelector div.active").each(function(idx, li) {
        checkedItems[counter] = $(li).text();
        counter++;
    });
filter.apps=checkedItems;
console.log($.param(filter));
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
 url: "/drilldown",
 data : filter  
});
```

[Image shows how the array is passed into the server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiTsk.png)