# How do I pass array of selected rows from a datatable to Flask?

Tags: python, jquery, flask, datatables

I am trying to get row information from my datatable in flask. The array shows data on the JQuery side, but is empty when accessed in flask. How can I pass my array so I can access it with python?

**Flask**

```
@api.route('/apply_billing')
def apply_billing():
    bill_month = request.args.get('bill_month', 0)
    markup = request.args.get('markup', 0, type=float)
    billed = request.args.get('billed', 0, type=float)
    comment = request.args.get('comment', 0, type=str)
    tickets = request.args.getlist('tickets')
    print(tickets)
    return jsonify(result=str(bill_month) + str(markup))
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('#submit').bind('click', function() {
        var ticket_array = [];
        $('#billinglist').DataTable().rows('.selected').every(function(rowIdx){
            ticket_array.push($('#billinglist').DataTable().row(rowIdx).data())
        });

       var data = {
           "bill_month": $('input[name="month"]').val(),
            "markup": $('input[name="markup"]').val(),
            "billed": $('input[name="billed"]').val(),
            "comment": $('input[name="comment"]').val(),
            "tickets": ticket_array
       }
       console.log(data)
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url_for('api.apply_billing') }}",
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                alert(response.result);
                $('#billinglist').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Try this way `url: '{% url "app:apply_billing" %}'` and `type: 'GET'`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but still have an empty array when I print it on the flask side

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using martijn-pieters's answer at [https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889107/sending-array-data-with-jquery-and-flask/40951200)

**Flask:**

```
@api.route('/apply_billing', methods=["POST"])
def apply_billing():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data["tickets"])
    return jsonify("test")
```

**JQuery**

```
<script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
    $('#submit').bind('click', function() {
        var ticket_array = [];
        $('#billinglist').DataTable().rows('.selected').every(function(rowIdx){
            ticket_array.push($('#billinglist').DataTable().row(rowIdx).data())
        });

       var data = {
            bill_month: $('input[name="month"]').val(),
            markup: $('input[name="markup"]').val(),
            billed: $('input[name="billed"]').val(),
            comment: $('input[name="comment"]').val(),
            tickets: ticket_array
       }
       console.log(data)
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ url_for('api.apply_billing') }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function(response) {
                alert(response.result);
                $('#billinglist').DataTable().ajax.reload();
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("No Bueno!!")
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
  });
</script>
```