# Send data from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python

I use the below code to send data (GET) from python to javascript.

in javascript:

```
$.get('http://localhost:5000/api/scan').success(function(res) {
        obj = JSON.parse(res);
        if(obj['channel'] == "1"){
        document.getElementById("channelZero").innerHTML = "1";
        }});
```

in python:

```
channels_str =  channels.getvalue()
data['channel'] = channels_str
return dumps(data)
```

how can I send data from javascript to python?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You've said "I'm sending data like this, how do I send data?"

Comment: @DanielRoseman he's saying "here is code that works sending data from python to javascript, now I want someone to write other code to send data from javascript to python"

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to do this vice-versa. I can send data from "python to javascript" but how is "javascript to python"?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778167/return-data-from-html-js-to-python/14778465#14778465

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case

```
$.get('http://localhost:5000/api/scan').success(function(res) {
    //your code
}});
```

you request **scan**, but if you add "?who=Masha" you send a parameter **who** with a value **"Masha"** as **get request** parameter.

```
$.get('http://localhost:5000/api/scan?who=Masha').success(function(res) {
    //your code
}});
```

Then if your python get response (typically `def do_GET(self):`)  has:

```
data['channel'] = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query).get('who', None)
```

---

Note that you need to import [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (In Python3, you'd use urllib.parse)

### import urlparse

From [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

> ## The GET Method
>
> #### Note that the query string (name/value pairs) is sent
>
> in the **URL** of a GET request:
>
> ```
> /test/demo_form.asp?name1=value1&name2=value2
> ```
>
> #### Some other notes on GET requests:
>
> - GET requests can be cached
> - GET requests remain in the browser history
> - GET requests can be bookmarked
> - GET requests should never be used when dealing with sensitive data
> - GET requests have length restrictions
> - GET requests should be used only to retrieve data