# Returning var from JavaScript to Python

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, python-webbrowser

I have an HTML container like this:

```
<div class="col-6">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-header py-2">Container Left</div>
    <div id="leftContainer" class="list-group" style="height:225px; overflow-y: scroll">
        {% for item in item_history %}
           <a href="#" data-set="5000" id = "{{forloop.counter}}" class="list-group-item py-0 list-group-item-action">{{ item }}</a>
        {% endfor %}                      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p id = "output"></p>    <!-- For DEBUG output -->
```

And I have a JS like this of which half is mine. I am able to print the value in the var `item_selected` back to the HTML page where the `<p id="output>"` is at.

```
<script>
    $("#leftContainer > a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#leftContainer > a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        var leftDataSet = parseInt($(this).attr("data-set"));        
        var item_selected = $(this).text();
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = item_selected

        // Found this while googling, supposed to send data back to Python.
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        // xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ // really not sure what this block does?!
        //     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        //         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        //     }
        // }
        xmlhttp.open("GET",item_selected,true);  // just send item_selected
        xmlhttp.send();
    });
</script>
```

I want to send the selection from the list box/container upon selection, which is currently stored in the JavaScript in the variable `item_selected`. I want to send this info back to Python which renders this page/template.

Can you help; I know Python 3, suck at JS/JQuery. My Framework used is Django. I render this page from the backend using `render` method like this:

```
# myapp/views.py
def render_view_results(self, request, projectid):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html',{'item_history':items})
```

Also, I do not want to send info back from HTML/JS to Python using the GET method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350511/send-data-from-javascript-to-python)

Comment: did you request successfully hitting server (python). If it then your item_selected value will be in request object. From Javascript you have to send item_selected in request query url. like this htpp:localhost/getItem?item=12

Comment: Is there a way to send to the Python server without sending it through a url?

Comment: You can use post method also to send data using ajax request.

Comment: How do I do that using ajax request?

Comment: Read this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13465711/how-do-i-post-with-jquery-ajax-in-django

Comment: @SameerAhmad: I read that link and I am failing at how to implement it :( I have made this Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/1bfiuy4qx8eI0bHY6GTv?p=preview

Comment: @SameerAhmad: Figured it out ;)

Comment: Cool. what was the issue?